# Mechanics behind the synchronisation of QPainters

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qpainter, qvariantanimation

## Context

I have a custom Widget which is supposed to make an animation of dots moving in order to make a kind of loading widget. To acheive that goal, I started using QPainter and QVariantAnimation objects, which seemed like a decent tools to do the job. The problem is that I think that the QPainters I initialise when drawing come in conflict with each other.

## Technique

To acheive that, I initialize multiple QVariantAnimation, which signal .valueChanged() I connect to a function update(), which is supposed to launch the painEvent(), such as written in the docs

> A paint event is a request to repaint all or part of a widget. It can happen for one of the following reasons:**repaint() or update() was invoked,
>   the widget was obscured and has now been uncovered, or
>   many other reasons.**

Since I start different animation at different times, I suppose that the update() is called many times, thus interfering with another QPainter already working. But, as I read in the docs,

> When update() is called several times or the window system sends several paint events, Qt merges these events into one event with a larger region.

But it specifies nothing id the QPainter has the same region, which is why I suposse it crashes. It logs messages such as:

```
QBackingStore::endPaint() called with active painter on backingstore paint device
```

## Minimal Working Example

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QDialog, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSlot, QVariantAnimation, QVariant, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QPainter, QBrush
import time

class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QDialog.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.resize(500, 500)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.button = QPushButton()
        self.layout().addWidget(self.button)
        self.paintWidget = PaintWidget()
        self.layout().addWidget(self.paintWidget)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.paintWidget.startPainting)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.reverse)

    def reverse(self):
        if self.paintWidget.isMoving:
            self.paintWidget.stopPainting()

class PaintWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PaintWidget, self).__init__()
        self.dotRadius = 10
        self.dotColor = QColor(255, 100, 100)
        self.numberOfDots = 3

        self.isMoving = False

        self.animation = []
        self.createAnimation()

        self.dotPosition = [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]

    def startPainting(self):
        for i in range(self.numberOfDots):
            self.animation[i].start()
            time.sleep(200)
        self.isActive = True

    def createAnimation(self):
        for i in range(self.numberOfDots):
            self.animation.append(QVariantAnimation(self, startValue=0, endValue=500, duration=3000))
            self.animation[i].valueChanged.connect(self.updatePosition)

    @pyqtSlot(QVariant)
    def updatePosition(self, position):
        self.dotPosition = [position, 0]
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.fillRect(self.rect(), Qt.transparent)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)

        for i in range(self.numberOfDots):
            painter.save()
            painter.translate(0, 0)
            position = (self.dotPosition[i][0], self.dotPosition[i][1])
            color = self.dotColor
            painter.setBrush(QBrush(color, Qt.SolidPattern))
            painter.drawEllipse(position[0], position[1], self.dotRadius, self.dotRadius)
            painter.restore()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dial = Dialog()
    dial.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

## Results

I know that for now this code wouldn't work because I can't retreive which dot's animation got updated, but **I believe the major problem here is the interference between the painters.** Thus, could anyone tell me why this is hapenning and point me in a potential solution? Also, For knowing the dot that got updated and chose the good position, I'm really unsure of how to do this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has the following errors:

- Never use time.sleep() in the main GUI thread since it blocks the event loop generating the freezing of the application.
- the variable dotPosition that must store all the positions you are replacing it with only one position in the updatePosition method.
- You should use QPoint if you are going to store a position instead of a list, use a list is not bad but using QPoint makes your code more readable.
- Do not use painter.save() and painter.restore() unnecessarily, neither painter.translate().

Considering the above, the solution is as follows:

```py
from functools import partial
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.resize(500, 500)

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.paintWidget = PaintWidget()

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.paintWidget.startPainting)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.button)
        lay.addWidget(self.paintWidget)


class PaintWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PaintWidget, self).__init__()
        self.dotRadius = 10
        self.dotColor = QtGui.QColor(255, 100, 100)

        self.animations = []

        self.dotPosition = [
            QtCore.QPoint(0, 0),
            QtCore.QPoint(0, 0),
            QtCore.QPoint(0, 0),
        ]

        self.createAnimation()

    def startPainting(self):
        for i, animation in enumerate(self.animations):
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(i * 200, animation.start)

    def createAnimation(self):
        for i, _ in enumerate(self.dotPosition):
            wrapper = partial(self.updatePosition, i)
            animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation(
                self,
                startValue=0,
                endValue=500,
                duration=3000,
                valueChanged=wrapper,
            )
            self.animations.append(animation)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int, QtCore.QVariant)
    def updatePosition(self, i, position):
        self.dotPosition[i] = QtCore.QPoint(position, 0)
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.fillRect(self.rect(), QtCore.Qt.transparent)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen)
        painter.setBrush(
            QtGui.QBrush(self.dotColor, QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        )

        for position in self.dotPosition:    
            painter.drawEllipse(position, self.dotRadius, self.dotRadius)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dial = Dialog()
    dial.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```